# I had XAMPP on my device but I have to uninstall it now my project does not run on localhost

Tags: php, xampp

XAMPP has some error about ports I uninstall it but did not back up any information and now my project does not run on local host is there any way for me to restore my old project or I have to do it again on new XAMPP? another problem is after reinstalling XAMPP windows do not know PHP what should I do?
by the way I am a very beginner in this :)))

Answer (score 1):

So, I will try to explain this:
Websites (i.e. with PHP) need a webserver. For example when you go to stackoverflow.com, you automatically call a webserver who then compiles the PHP scripts on the server to HTML code.

This principe does also apply to your local installation.
When you call localhost, you basically call yourself as the webserver. XAMPP is a tool that can "simulate" a webserver on your PC, thats why PHP sites do not work without it, because your browser doesn't know what to do with PHP code, it only understands HTML.

If you install XAMPP again you should be able to get it running.
If you have any questions/problems with the XAMPP installation, feel free to ask again.